# /var/lib/mysql folder is missing

Tags: mysql, httpd, yum

I've created a virtual machine and am installing things from scratch. Definitely not a sys admin so I'm running into some trouble. I've installed these packages and then restarted httpd

```
yum -y install mysql
yum -y install php-mysql
yum -y install mysql-devel
service httpd restart
```

The httpd restart is successful yet I am still getting this error:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'
```

I looked at `/etc/my.cnf` and indeed, `socket` is pointing to that path.

But the `/var/lib/mysql` folder does not even exist, nor do some files which seem crucial such as `/etc/init.d/mysql`. Am I missing some other important MySQL yum package? Why would some files (such as my.cnf) exist while others don't?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's likely that you need to install the mysql-server package.

```
yum install mysql-server
```

You can search for packages by name with some of the following yum commands:

```
# list all packages starting with "mysql"
yum list mysql\*

# search package names/summaries/descriptions for "mysql"
yum search mysql
```

The packages which you did install likely provided only the client and client libraries, which you could use to connect to a mysql server located on another host.

Comment: That did it, thanks for explaining the difference between client/server and also showing me how to search for mysql-related packages!

Comment: Same issue now I am faceing, but one thing, that I didnt know that what packages are installed in Linux server. So just I ran your command and the results are 1.  List: `Error: No matching Packages to list` and 2. Search: `Warning: No matches found for: mysql
No Matches found`... How can I found that where was Mysql installed on Linux machine..?